# vb.net system.outofmemoryexception while writing to buffer

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I'm having some trouble with an app that receives bytes from a serial port.
The problem occurs in the SerialPort1_DataReceived event. The machine I'm using sends binary through the serial port and I write each byte into a buffer. The maximum amount of bytes that it will send is 32mb. Here are my declarations:

```
Dim count As Integer = 35000000
Dim buffer(count - 1) As Byte
Dim readBytes As Integer
Dim totalReadBytes As Integer
Dim offset As Integer
Dim remaining As Integer = count
```

I declare these Publically.

Here is my code for reading the bytes, this is in the SerialPort1_DataReceived event:

```
SerialPort1.BaudRate = 230400
SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 5000

Try
 Do
  readBytes = SerialPort1.Read(buffer, offset, remaining)
  offset += readBytes
  remaining -= readBytes
  totalReadBytes += readBytes
 Loop While remaining > 0 AndAlso readBytes > 0

 Catch ex As System.TimeoutException
   milking_binary = False
   ReDim Preserve buffer(totalReadBytes - 1)

   oFileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(selected_file, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
   oFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
   oFileStream.Close()
   MsgBox("Milk Complete", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
   SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 160000
   SerialPort1.BaudRate = 115200
   idle = True

   count = 35000000
   readBytes = 0
   totalReadBytes = 0
   offset = 0
   remaining = count

   ReDim buffer(count - 1)

   set_info()
 End Try
```

What it does is, each time a byte is received it writes it into the buffer, the buffer size is set to 35mb. Then when it times out, meaning no more bytes are being received, it uses a filestream and writes the buffer to the file stream. (I'm probably not explaining this properly, but thats not what I need help with). This works great if the bytes im receiving is low.. but if the bytes that are received gets bigger than about 15mb it crashes the whole app and gives me an error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

My guess is that the buffer is using too much ram.. Is there a way that I can write incoming bytes as they are received? Or is am I going about this the wrong way.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully that means "milli-byte", considering how slow serial ports are.   The exception suggests it doesn't :)  The transfer takes almost an hour.   The OOM cause is not very obvious, a simple workaround here is to use a small buffer, 4096 bytes is fine, and write it directly to the file instead of waiting to get *everything*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. The problem is I'm struggling to figure out a way to empty the buffer into a file, while its being filled.

Comment: Makes no sense, you don't "empty" a buffer.  SerialPort.Read() puts bytes in the buffer, its return value tells you how many.  Just call FileStream.Write() to write them to the file.